# Calling KieScanner throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, drools, wildfly-8, drools-guvnor, kie

I have several Drools projects and would like to be able to dynamically load rules changes. The projects all work fine until I tried to add KieScanner to them. I followed the directions here: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html/DroolsReleaseNotesChapter.html#d0e515

I am using drools 6.1.0.Final with Wildfly 8.0.0.Final

The documentation indicates that having the dependency for the kie-ci in my class path was enough. Clearly either I am doing something wrong or the documentation is wrong.

The project builds but when it is called, I get this trace:

10:21:17,946 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /catalog/vetec/search/facets/term: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/repository/internal/MavenRepositorySystemSession
    at org.kie.scanner.MavenRepository.getMavenRepository(MavenRepository.java:73) [kie-ci-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.kie.scanner.ArtifactResolver.(ArtifactResolver.java:36) [kie-ci-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.getArtifactResolver(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:87) [kie-ci-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.getArtifactVersion(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:108) [kie-ci-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl$KieModuleRepo.load(KieRepositoryImpl.java:281) [drools-compiler-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl$KieModuleRepo.load(KieRepositoryImpl.java:267) [drools-compiler-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:90) [drools-compiler-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.getKieModule(KieRepositoryImpl.java:77) [drools-compiler-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:97) [drools-compiler-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
    at com.sial.rules.cdi.KSessionContextProvider.(KSessionContextProvider.java:49) [sial-rules-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sial.rules</groupId>
  <artifactId>sial-rules</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss Repository</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>   
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Added to ensure that we have the correct DROOLS/JBOSS versions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>                        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>                   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>knowledge-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
                      <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                           <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
                           <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                      </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0-rc1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
  <build>
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
         <artifactId>drools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>6.0.0.CR5</version>
         <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build> 
</project>
```

This business rules project is itself incorporated into the actual WARs that are deployed to Wildfly.This is the dependency used in the application poms:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sial.rules</groupId>
            <artifactId>sial-rules</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

I recently discovered that the extra dependency breaks our Arquillian Unit tests. Since Arquillian has a completely different maven integration, my best guess is that this is a bug in KIE. It is very similar to [BZ1098018](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1098018)

Adding this extra dependency "fixes" the issue when the code actually calls kie-ci, however with this dependency our Arquillian tests fail to deploy.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-aether-provider</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that kie-ci includes an older version of maven (3.0.5) than does Arquillian (3.1.1) Specifically the maven-aether-provider. Arquillian (really ShrinkWrap) really wants to use the newer version.

I tried forcing the 3.0.5 version in the pom.xml but get the issue of the resolver.
This is the error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to boostrap Aether repository system. Make sure you're running Maven 3.1.0 or newer.

So basically kie 6.1.0.Final is incompatible with Arquillian 1.1.5.Final

I will have to see if the Kie 6.2.0CR3 release will work

Comment: I was able to force Arquillian to use the older maven version

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to declare the additional maven, aether and other dependencies manually. The kie-ci should transitively depend on everything it needs. If you look at the pom.xml of the kie-ci https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/6.1.0.Final/kie-ci/pom.xml the dependencies you added are also listed there, so Maven resolves them automatically.

This seems to be either some weird bug or misconfiguration. I presume you have the following in your pom:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Could you post your whole pom?

Comment: Maven did not resolve them automatically. I had to explicitly add them. I do have to exclude netty as netty doesn't play well with applications in Wildfly.

Comment: In that case it does not seem to be an issue with the kie-ci itself, but rather with the war build. The kie-ci POM clearly depends on those maven and aether artifacts, so Maven should be able to transitively resolve them. There are several examples where this works, so could this be some kind of configuration issue on your side? If it is at all possible, please post your whole pom.xml file. Without that is it very hard to guess what is actually wrong.

Comment: We build 3 different applications two use 1 set of rules while the third uses another. I edited the question to add the full pom.xml of our business rules project. This project is a dependency in the others.
We use CDI to inject KieSessions in the other projects. The application wars simply include the business rules project dependency. All three projects had the same issue with resolving the kie-ci transitive dependencies.

Comment: Do you specify those addition maven dependencies in the rules pom or the application (war) one? It seems that the WAR file(s) simply does not contain the transitive dependencies. I don't really know why though. One other comment: you should use `org.kie:kie-maven-plugin` instead of `org.drools:drools-maven-plugin`

Comment: Unless I add org.apahce.maven:maven-aether-provider explicitly to the pom.xml I get errors. However, when I do add it Arquillian fails to deploy its test war so my Unit tests are broken. Seems like there is a problem with the pom, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: I was able to trim the extra dependencies down to a single one. However, that still seems to be required.
My problem is a lot like BZ1098018. I don't have a Spring component, but otherwise this seems like a KIE Bug.